# How to print something a specific number of times based on user input?

Tags: python

So I'm a beginner to Python, I don't know many things and I'm stuck on one specific thing.

I don't know how to print `{variable}` number of times stored in `choice`

Sorry if this sound stupid

```
choice = input("How many time do you want to {something}: ")
{variable} = "{something}"
# End of Variables

if choice_number > 0:
    print({variable})
```

I'm very sorry, if my question sounds weird English isn't my first language..

Comment: Please use good naming conventions.
Also, try googling stuff before you ask here on StackOverflow.
To help you out, if `x` is a variable, doing `x*n` prints it `n` times
See [Python PEP8 Guidlines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `for` loop:

```
choice = input("How many times do you want to print {something}: ")
variable = "{something}"

for i in range(int(choice)):
    print(variable)
```

We use `int(choice)` to transform the string that user input gets parsed as, into an integer. Then we use the built-in function `range()` to create a list of numbers from zero until that integer, and iterate through them with a variable named `i`. We don't *do* anything with `i` (though we could), just print `variable` once for every iteration.

Will print

```
{something}
{something}
{something}
...
```

Comment: You can also control what is printed at the end of each `print` call, with the `end` argument to the `print` function. In this case and by default, `end = '\n'` (newline), so each `{something}` is followed by a newline, so the next `print` call begins on the next line. You could for example set `end` to `" "` (space) so that the output will be `{something} {something} {something}...`.

The end argument would be specified by doing `print(variable, end = " ")`.

Answer (score 2):

*Green Cloak Guy*'s magnificent answer is definitely the best if you want to print the same thing on multiple lines.
For the sake of completeness, I think it would be helpful for you to learn that in python you can multiply a string by a number. Let's see an example:

```
choice = input("How many times do you want to print {something}: ")
variable = "{something}"

print(variable * int(choice))
```

*variable* will be printed `choice` times on the same line.
Your output will be:

> {something}{something}{something}{something}...

Answer (score 1):

usually, in many languages, when you wanna `do_something()` , `x` times
what you do is use a loop.

```
for i in range(x):
     do_something()
```

here:

```
choice = int(input("How many time do you want to {something}: "))
variable = "{something}"
#} End of Variables

if choice > 0:
    for i in range(choice):
        print(variable)
```

notice that I did some syntax cleanup